# Check if a service is deployed to the cluster programatically

Tags: c#, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I got a c# code which is supposed to check if a service deployment exists on a k8s cluster. This check is being done before doing other actions like `helm install` for example.

Until now I checked if a deployment exists like this:

```
try
{
 var output = _helmCommands.HelmRun($"status {helmChartName} -n {namespace}");
 if (output.Contains(@"STATUS: deployed"))
 {
   return true;
 }
}
catch { return false; }
```

It worked for a while but now I've encountered an issue where the output says that the status is "failed" instead of "deployed" but for all intents and purposes of deleting or installing a service with the same name, the deployment does exist.

I wanted to ask what is the correct condition to check that a deployment of a service exists. Do I need to simply check that the status is not an empty string (since if there is no deployment an exception is thrown)? Or is there something else I need to check?

Comment: If you have a look at the output of the helm status command you can find that you could also simply check for NAME: {helmChartName} as your assumption is correct, helm will output `Error: release: not found` if a release doesn't exist

Comment: @fantaztig it will do it with an exception right?

Comment: Depends on how your HelmRun method works internally but the return code will be 1

Comment: but it returns a string message, not an integer code

Comment: So what is your question now, your method returns a string, you can check that for the helm chart name, what is left open to answer?

Comment: What is left is what I actually asked.. my method returns the standard output of the helm chart command. The question is if it's correct to assume that an image exists if the standard output is not empty and if it always throws an exception in case the image doesn't exist

Comment: As I said, that depends on how your helm chart command works internally. I cannot tell you whether it will throw an exception in case the respective binary returns a nonzero exit code

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the easiest and most complete solution would be to run `helm list -a -A` and parse the result to discover all the releases deployed on your cluster. Results from helm list will look something like this:

```
NAME            NAMESPACE           REVISION    UPDATED                                 STATUS      CHART                   APP VERSION
cert-manager    cert-manager        4           2022-03-01 19:02:17.947432993 +0000 UTC deployed    cert-manager-v1.7.1     v1.7.1
fluent-bit      fluent-bit          4           2022-03-02 14:19:56.610347 +0100 CET    deployed    fluent-bit-0.19.19      1.8.12
gatekeeper      gatekeeper-system   5           2022-03-01 10:00:53.81287 +0100 CET     deployed    gatekeeper-3.7.1        v3.7.1
ingress-nginx   ingress-nginx       1           2022-02-23 18:17:55.019592 +0100 CET    deployed    ingress-nginx-4.0.17    1.1.1
linkerd-viz     linkerd-viz         3           2022-03-03 16:28:25.201894 +0100 CET    deployed    linkerd-viz-2.11.1      stable-2.11.1
loki            monitoring          3           2022-01-20 16:06:58.796303027 +0100 CET deployed    loki-stack-2.5.0        v2.1.0
```

You can of course also narrow your search down further by using filters [as described in the docs](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_list/).

Comment: I understand your solution but I don't understand why the way I suggested of checking the deployment won't work. What I suggested sounds much easier